# Question about まんず

Tags: translation, dialects

I'm trying to translate one of the Japanese stories (currently this one: [節分の鬼](http://hukumusume.com/douwa/pc/jap/02/03.htm)) to get better understanding of the language (as I'm still a beginner, but stubborn) and the whole thing was going smoothly until this part:

> 「んだ、んだ。こんなうれしい事はねえ。まんずあたらしてけろ」
>   と、ズカズカと家に入り込んで来ました。

I just cannot grasp this particular sentence: まんずあたらしてけろ.

Before asking for help I've searched throughout the web but with little luck, apart from てけろ which, after some digging, I'm kinda convince it is a dialectical version of てください. According to Google Translate (not a great source) the meaning of the sentence is 'Make sure to warm up'. Sounds right by a long shot, considering the previous sentences in the story.

Can anyone help me with breaking this apart? I begin to think this is really all about being cold but it just doesn't click for me still (maybe because of it being some dialect thing or a fixed phrase?)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- まんず is a dialectal way of saying まず ("first of all", "before anything").
- ～てけろ is ～てください in Tohoku dialect.
- あたらす is a causative form of あたる. (See "shortened causative form" [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass))
- あたる in this context is [火にあたる](http://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/18934/) ("to get warm by the fire"). 火に is omitted. See the definition **1**㋒ in [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/4694/meaning/m0u/).

So in standard Japanese, the sentence is まず(火に)あたらせてください, which is translated as "Let me get warm first" or "First of all, allow me to get warm".